# Raspberrypi connection to PLC - No module named pycomm

Tags: raspbian, python

I have a weird problem.

So I have a unit that I am controlling with PLC and I have 2 RaspberryPi's.

One of them (#1) is able to communicate through the PLC and everything, I am using pycomm commands and module and everything is ok. But, this Pi has an issue -> " No wireless interfaces found " 
The other one (#2), I am using the same codes, and all the modules are installed in the same folders, but it always says "ImportError: no module named 'pycomm'

I have thought of cloning #1 to #2, but therefore I will have to deal with the wireless issues. So I want to fix #2, and then I will clone it to #1. I dont want to touch #1 right now since thats the only way I can communicate with PLC.

My code is as below:

```
from pycomm.ab_comm.clx import Driver as ClxDriver
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import time
import csv
import string
import logging

mudSkid = ClxDriver()
IP_address = '10.94.0.77'

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO, filename = 'mudskid_logger.log')
```

## connection with the Mud Skid Unit

```
if mudSkid.open('10.94.0.77'):
    print ('Connected to skid unit')
else:
    print ('Connection failed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the module installed (`pip install pycomm`)?
You can check by running `pip show pycomm`.
It should return no output if the module **is not** installed, or output about the module if it **is** installed.

Furthermore, if you have both python2 and python3 installed, pay attention to the fact that there's a different pip for each of them (`pip` and `pip3`).